# How to calculate <LatLonBox> coordinates in KML for a Image Overlay

Tags: coordinates, kml

Does anyone know the answer to calculate the "" coordinates 
using a image for the ImageOverlay?

Data: 
 - Having a image in size 320x320 
 - Having a north co-ordinate

Needed: 
1. I need steps to find the other 3 coordinates using the above available 
data for the Image overlay  element..

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you'll need 2 diagonal coordinates. With just a single coordinate, you cannot correlate pixels to distance.